# Error: "Input string was not in a correct format" on false statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, tryparse

My code is working fine if the statement (numtickets > tickav) is true (if tickets available is greater than tickets ordered) But if other wise, it throws in this error "FormatException was unhandled by user code, Input string was not in a correct format" on int numTick = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfTickets.Text);
I do know that somehow I can use tryparse, i need help putting it in the code.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you

```
 namespace TicketsApp
 {
 public partial class TicketOrder : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["description"] != null && Session["EventID"] != null &&                             Session["numtickets"] != null && Session["ticketcost"] != null
            && Session["State"] != null && Session["Section"] != null && Session["Row"] != null && Session["date"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    txtEventDescription.Text = Session["description"].ToString();
                    txtEventID.Text = Session["EventID"].ToString();
                    txtTicketsAvailable.Text = Session["numtickets"].ToString();
                    txtTicketCost.Text = Session["ticketcost"].ToString();
                    txtState.Text = Session["State"].ToString();
                    txtSectionNumber.Text = Session["Section"].ToString();
                    txtRowNumber.Text = Session["Row"].ToString();

                    txtNumberOfTickets.Focus();
                    lblOutput.Visible = false;

                }
                catch
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Please Search for Tickets First!";
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                    btnOrderTickets.Visible = false;
                    Response.Redirect("TicketSearch.aspx");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    protected void btnOrderTickets_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TicketsDataAccessDataContext NewOrder = new TicketsDataAccessDataContext();

        int numTick = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfTickets.Text);
        string s = txtTotalCost.Text.Substring(1);
        int totc = Convert.ToInt32(s);
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtEventID.Text);
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["date"]);

        int returnedValue = NewOrder.PlaceOrderFull(id, txtEventDescription.Text, dt, Session["State"].ToString(), Session["section"].ToString(), Session["Row"].ToString(), numTick, totc, "vfateev");
        if (returnedValue != 0)
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "Error has occured. Please try again";
            lblOutput.Visible = true;
            btnOrderTickets.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lblOutput.Visible = true;
            lblOutput.Text = "Thank you";
            btnOrderTickets.Visible = false;
        }

    }

    protected void txtNumberOfTickets_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cos = Convert.ToInt32(txtTicketCost.Text);
        int numtickets = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfTickets.Text);
        int tickav = Convert.ToInt32(txtTicketsAvailable.Text);

        if (numtickets > tickav)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Please Enter a valid ticket quantity";
            lblError.Visible = true;

            lblOutput.Text = "";
            txtNumberOfTickets.Text = "";
        }


        else
        {

            int cost = cos * numtickets + 5;
            txtTotalCost.Text = "$" + cost.ToString();
            lblOutput.Visible = false;
            lblFee.Text = "There is a $5 shipping fee";
            lblFee.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "";}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what number are you putting in the textbox?

Comment: @DanielA.White my textboxes auto populate from sql table. if i enter bigger number in my txtnumberoftickets(numtickets) than txtticketsavailable (tickav), thats when if throws an error, but if numTickets < tickav, then everything is working fine

Comment: so all my textboxes autopopulate with numbers except my txtnumberoftickets, where user enters the number

Comment: You're going to have other logical problems with your implementation.  You're using txtTotalCost to store your ticket price but then you're modifying txtTotalCost when you change quantity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of your methods rewritten using Int32.TryParse.  I assumed you're doing txtTotalCost.Substring(1) to trim off the currency symbol.  There are probably safe ways to do this, I'm just going to trim "$" for this example.

```
protected void btnOrderTickets_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfTickets, ticketCost, eventId;
    if(Int32.TryParse(txtNumberOfTickets.Text, out numberOfTickets) &&
        Int32.TryParse(txtTotalCost.Text.TrimStart('$'), out ticketCost) &&
        Int32.TryParse(txtEventID.Text, out eventId))
    {
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["date"]);

        TicketsDataAccessDataContext NewOrder = new TicketsDataAccessDataContext();
        int returnedValue = NewOrder.PlaceOrderFull(eventId, txtEventDescription.Text, dt, Session["State"].ToString(), Session["section"].ToString(), Session["Row"].ToString(), numberOfTickets, ticketCost, "vfateev");
        if (returnedValue != 0)
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "Error has occured. Please try again";
            lblOutput.Visible = true;
            btnOrderTickets.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lblOutput.Visible = true;
            lblOutput.Text = "Thank you";
            btnOrderTickets.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblOutput.Visible = true;
        lblOutput.Text = "Some validation error message here...";
    }
}
```

You will need to make similar modifications to `txtNumberOfTickets_TextChanged1` to ensure the user has entered valid text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use int.TryParse which returns a boolean and does not throw an exception.

```
int numTick = 0;
bool result = int.TryParse(txtNumberOfTickets.Text, out numTick );
```

You can also do some client side validation to ensure that the field is filled in and contains a number.

Comment: Thanks, thats what im trying to do but where in code i can put it?

Comment: If i replace int numTick = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfTickets.Text); with int numTick = 0;
bool result = int.TryParse(txtNumberOfTickets.Text, out numTick ); I get another error on line string s = txtTotalCost.Text.Substring(1); Error: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Comment: What do you expect txtTotalCost.Text.Substring(1); to do if the user hasn't entered anything into the txtTotalCost textbox?

Comment: @Bananamansam thats an issue as well, it kicks off the same error if i dont put anything

Answer (score 0):

simply use something like 
To use IsNumeric in C#, add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll then

```
if (Information.IsNumeric(value))
   {
    DoSomthing();
   }
   else
   {
    DoSomethingElse();
   }
```

**UPDATE**
OPEN VISUAL STUDIO ==> YOUR PROJECT

Click on solution and add reference, choose Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll confrim the new reference will be add to your references into the project.

Go at the top of your page and declare the import statemnet for Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll alias

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll;
```

then where you need to check the value of your textbox

```
 if (Information.IsNumeric(yourtextbox.text.trim()))
   {
    //case true alias your value is numeric 
        //do what you need here like assing value to a var or any
        //else
   }
   else
   {
         //put your logic here in case result is false and value 
         //is not numeric
   }
```

Comment: im lost sorry, im a newbie